# Directing page from get usertype string error java

Tags: java

i already have this in my program:

[image]

The box says that i have logged in as "Admin - Administrator", Note that "Admin is the username that stored in the database" and "Administrator is the usertype that stored in the database"

Here is my code that shows that "Admin - Administrator":

```
user = result.getString("Username");
userType = result.getString("UserType");

_userInformation.setUser(user);
_userInformation.setUserType(userType);

_infoBox.ShowMessageBox("Welcome \n You Have Logged in as : \n" + _userInformation.getUser() + " - " + _userInformation.getUserType() + " ! ", "Welcome" , 1);
```

However, when i tried to direct the page based on the usertype, it gave me nothing (the page didn't directed or the program stop at the image that shown at the above), here is my code after user click the ok button in that messagebox:

```
if (_userInformation.getUserType() == "Administrator")
{
    this.dispose();

    _adminChoices.setVisible(true);
}
```

When i trace the _userInformation.getUserType(), it gave me this:

[image]

Could you guys help me? Thanks!

Comment: Should be `if (_userInformation.getUserType().equals("Administrator"))`. Don't compare Strings using ==. Use equals() instead. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Thanks! Solved! I thought it can be use sign == than equals in java. i Just saw your post @ZouZou, now i know what is the difference between sign == and word equals. Thanks again!